# Downloading a file in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have this script that runs and downloads a file automatically in Android Chrome but it did not run in my Android Webview.

```
<script>
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
}

download('test.txt', 'Hello world!');

</script>
```

Is there a way to do this? If there is, then how?
Thanks!

EDITED:
I also switched the `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` function but it is still not capable of downloading a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need run JavaScript in webview, so need enable JavaScript executable on webview.

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);                                                                                                                                                             
    // Enable JavaScript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```